# Java .bin url for cloud server installation

Tags: java

I am trying to install java on a fedora core on cloud server by doing so:

wget -O /java/jdk-6u6-linux-i586.bin http://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/VerifyItem-Start/jdk-6u6-linux-i586.bin?BundledLineItemUUID=ACBIBe.lcAEAAAEa0f1UGJK0&OrderID=KodIBe.ljeAAAAEaxP1UGJK0&ProductID=VXZIBe.ootIAAAEZTrBAkQve&FileName=/jdk-6u6-linux-i586.bin

however, i don't believe that this is a valid download link. Would anyone know a valid link?

Thanks, tone